# java.net.ConnectException / java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-boot, azure

I'm following a tutorial about Spring Boot and Azure. on my first test, I got this error and searched a lot but I didn't found any solution.

I have set the Env Variable, Azure account, key and it was success with Postman, Here I want to make my own client as followed by tutorial..

```
package com.azure.app;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest
class AzureAppApplicationTests {

@Value("${AZURE_API_KEY}")
private String azureApiKey;
private static final String AZURE_ENDPOINT ="https://**.**.cognitiveservices.azure.com";
private static final String AZURE_ENDPOINT_PATH ="text/analytics/v3.0/entities/recognition/general";
private static final String API_KEY_HEADER_NAME ="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE ="Content-Type";
private static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";
private static final String EXAMPLE_JSON ="{"
        + " \"document\": [ "
        + "      { "
        + "       \"language\" : \"en\" ,"
        + "        \"id\": \"1\","
        + "         \"text\": \" M&Z has been found on 2020\""
        + "      }"
        + "     ]"
        + "   }";


@Test
public void getEntities() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 /*
  - Create the client
  - Create the request
  - Send the request and receive the response
  - Work with the response
 */


     HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
      HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME,azureApiKey)
            .uri(URI.create(AZURE_ENDPOINT + AZURE_ENDPOINT_PATH))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(EXAMPLE_JSON))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
    System.out.println(response.body());
  }
}
```

**Error Page**

```
java.net.ConnectException
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:563)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at com.azure.app.AzureAppApplicationTests.getEntities(AzureAppApplicationTests.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.toConnectException(Utils.java:1034)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:179)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.AsyncSSLConnection.connectAsync(AsyncSSLConnection.java:56)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.createAsync(Http2Connection.java:369)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2ClientImpl.getConnectionFor(Http2ClientImpl.java:127)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ExchangeImpl.get(ExchangeImpl.java:93)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.establishExchange(Exchange.java:306)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl0(Exchange.java:438)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsyncImpl(Exchange.java:343)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.responseAsync(Exchange.java:335)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:347)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl$7(MultiExchange.java:384)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandleStage(CompletableFuture.java:946)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.handle(CompletableFuture.java:2337)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsyncImpl(MultiExchange.java:374)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.lambda$responseAsync0$2(MultiExchange.java:293)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1146)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1776)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:155)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2670)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.responseAsync(MultiExchange.java:246)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.sendAsync(HttpClientImpl.java:643)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:542)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkRemote(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:722)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectAsync$0(PlainHttpConnection.java:165)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:167)
    ... 90 more
```

Any solution would be much appreciated.